# How can I have jquery attach behavior to an element after inserting it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form that I submit through ajax, and returns an updated chunk of html that includes an updated form that I want to submit through jquery.

The problem I am having is that the first time I click submit the event is captured by jquery and works great. When I make another change to the form without refreshing, the event is not captured by jquery, but makes a standard post request.

How can I have jquery attach behavior to an element after inserting it.

Here is my jquery code.

```
$('.edit_clothing_product').submit(function(){
  var productDiv = $(this).parent();
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  var formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.post(action, formData, function(data){
  productDiv.replaceWith(data);
  });
  return false;
 });
```

Here is the (trimmed down) HTML that I return.

```
<div class="product">
    <form action="..." class="edit_clothing_product">
      <div class="color_combos">
        ...{form fields}
      </div>
      <a href=".../add_color_combo" class="add_color_combo">Add Color Combo</a>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to re-attach the submit event handler you defined because you are replacing the form. You can make this entire thing a callable function so you can invoke it multiple times.

As far as I know, `live` doesn't work for `submit` - you might be able to attach a `click` event handler with `live` but it's not the *exact* same thing as `.submit`. I would just define a function like so:

```
function handleForm( el ) {
$(el).submit(function(){
  var productDiv = $(el).parent();
  var action = $(el).attr('action');
  var formData = $(el).serialize();

  $.post(action, formData, function(data){
      productDiv.replaceWith(data);
      var form = data.find('form');
      handleForm( form );
  });
  return false;
 });
}

handleForm('.edit_clothing_product')
```

If you feel lazy, attach `.live('click', function() {} );` to your submit button but if it gets submitted without a click it wont work so it has its drawbacks.

```
$('.edit_clothing_product #submitButton').live('click', function(){
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  var productDiv = form.parent();
  var action = $(form).attr('action');
  var formData = $(form).serialize();

  $.post(action, formData, function(data){
      productDiv.replaceWith(data);
  });
  return false;
 });
```

You might also be able to use `liveQuery` but I never really used that.

Comment: As someone new to jQuery (and JS), could I ask the obvious: *how do I re-attach the submit event handler..?*

Comment: Updated `this` keyword to `el` - from the looks of it this *should* function. Let me know if it doesn't. Make sure that the `var form` is a correct reference please.

Comment: You are right! Should not have overlooked that live() does not work with submit. Just deleted my answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I had thought about creating a function to handle the event, but didn't try...I because I thought it would create a loop.  I tried .live(), but didn't get the results I wanted, I will try this in the next hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

Meder pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

One thing I forgot to mention was that I had multiple product divs on a page, which meant I had to invoke the function for each.

Also, I was not able to re-attach the submit event directly to the form I just inserted, but I was able to re-attach to all the product forms.  It works, but seems a little clumsy, let me know if I should not do it this way.

Here's the final jquery

```
function handleForm( el ) {
$(el).submit(function(){
  var productDiv = $(el).parent();
  var action = $(el).attr('action');
  var formData = $(el).serialize();

  $.post(action, formData, function(data){
      productDiv.replaceWith(data)
      $('.edit_clothing_product').each(function(){
        handleForm(this);
    });
  });
  return false;
 });
}

$('.edit_clothing_product').each(function(){
    handleForm(this);
});
```

Comment: Still having issues, the code above caused some strange behavior, after I tried to update multiple forms at one time.  I also dynamically add "color combo fields" to the form, which the link to do so gets inserted after update as well.